# How can I create this line wave effect using Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

How do I create this water-like line wave effect ( same as image above) using Adobe Illustrator

Answer (score 1):

Start by creating two lines with gradients applied to the stroke. In the gradient window use `Apply gradient along stroke` to orient the gradient correctly
[image: Two Lines with Gradients]

Next select the blend tool and use it to blend the two lines. [image]

With the blend tool still selected hit enter to open the blend options dialogue. I think you'll find that specified distance works well, use the preview checkbox to adjust to your liking.
[image]

Next draw a simple line representing the path you'd like your blend to follow.
[image]

Finally select both your blend and the new path and go to `Object > Blend > Replace Spline` to align your blend to your new path.
[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

Using the **Blend tool** and **Align to Page option applied to a blend**

https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/blending-objects.html

[image]

Comment: there's more than just that... care to [edit] and give a more complete answer?